# Android app icon not updating on the S4

Tags: android, icons, samsung-mobile

To make this question more relevant to the general users out there, if you are having problems with your app icon not being what you want it to be, or something similar, make sure that your icon is the same across all `drawable` folders.

I'm running into this issue with my app icon, affectionately named `ic_launcher.png`. I have been testing my app on the Samsung Galaxy S4 [Sprint] [Stock] and the first icon showed up and everything was normal. I recently changed the app icon to something else, (with the same name, i just made a different icon for it) but the old icon just won't go away when I install the app on the s4. I have cleared data and cache and uninstalled several times, I have even changed the package name, I'm fairly certain this TouchWiz specific because I have CM10.1 on my SII and it updated the icon fine. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: "affectionately"? :-) Try rebooting -- some home screens cache this information for a while.

Comment: Maybe you have the old icon in the drawable-xxhdpi folder? because s4 will get the icon from this folder

Comment: @maclir That was the problem. I guess I just overlooked it. I don't have much in that folder, so I guess i just forgot to delete that. Thanks.

Comment: It happens to me a similar issue, but the problem was an icon in a different project (a library), that had the same name of app's icon and was also set in its own manifest. Removing the icon and the entry from the library's manifest solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the old icon in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder? because **s4** will get the launcher icon from this folder.